# splash doesn't wait when scrapy endpoint='render.json'

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I am trying to get the content from iframe for this reason I changed my splash request endpoint from execute to render.json. Howerver, splash.wait doesn't work at all. Here's the spider code.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
src="""
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(10))
  return {
    html = splash:html()
  }
end

"""

class Lafarge (scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lafargespider"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.root_url = "https://cacareers-lafarge-na.icims.com/jobs/search?pr=0&searchRelation=keyword_all&schemaId=&o="

    def start_requests(self):
           yield SplashRequest(self.root_url, self.parse_detail,
                endpoint='render.json',
                args={
                    'iframes': 1,
                    'html' : 1,
                    'lua_source': src,
                    'timeout': 90
                }
            ) 
    def parse_detail(self, response):
        #response decoded
        rs = response.data['childFrames'][0]['html']
        response = HtmlResponse(url="my HTML string", body=rs, encoding='utf-8')
        print("next page ===>",response.xpath('//a[@class="glyph "]/@href').extract_first())
```

Answer (score 1):

passing wait time in the Splash.request arguments solved the issue for me.

```
def start_requests(self):
       yield SplashRequest(self.root_url, self.parse_detail,
            endpoint='render.json',
            args={
                'wait': 5,
                'iframes': 1,
                'html' : 1,
                'lua_source': src,
            }
        ) 
def parse_detail(self, response):
    rs = response.data['childFrames'][0]['html']
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the wait param in args. It should be -

args ={
       'wait': 5,
       'iframes': 1,
       'html' : 1,
       'lua_source': src,
       'timeout': 90
     }

Answer (score 0):

lua_source isn't supported with endpoint of type "render.json" but supported with type "execute" so no need for lua_source in your code.

What solved the problem is using wait see explanation for wait usage here page 11:
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/splash/latest/splash.pdf